# Sum multiple ActiveQuery subquery in select

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have the following tables

**Product**

```
id name 
1  Alcohol
2  Candy
3  Soda
```

**ProductIn**

```
id item_no count date
1  1       10   2018/01/01
2  1       20   2018/01/07
3  2       10   2018/01/08
4  3       10   2018/01/08
```

**ProductOut**

```
id item_no count date 
1  1       10   2018/01/02 
2  1       10   2018/01/09 
3  2       2    2018/01/09
4  3       3    2018/01/11
```

I would like to get the sum of the product actual quantity
by doing

```
select *, 
  (sum(select sum(count) from ProductIn where ProductIn.item_no = product.itemno) -
   sum(select sum(count) from ProductOut where ProductOut.item_no = product.itemno)) as availableQty
from product
```

currently im doing this like using ActiveQuery

```
$main_query = Product::find();

$data = [];
foreach ($main_query->all() as $model) {
    $query1 = ProductIn::find()
                ->filterWhere(['=', 'item_code', $model->item_no])
                ->asArray()->one();

    $query2 = ProductOut::find()
                ->filterWhere(['=', 'item_code', $model->item_no])
                ->asArray()->one();

    $allModels[$model->item_no] = ['item_no' => $model->item_no, 'name' => $model->name,  'availableQty' => ($query1 - $query2)];
}
```

but looping on every record is slow I wanted to combine the 3 ActiveQuery.

I was able to include the subquery to main_query by using

```
 $main_query->addSelect($query1)
```

but i cannot get the difference of the two subquery as one field.

Is there any way to do this on ActiveQuery?

Comment: add expected query result also.

Answer (score 0):

Here's few Suggestions for you -

1. No need loop duplicate queries in forloop (i.e. $query1 & $query2)
2. Just collect all `item_codes` required for `ProductIn` and `ProductOut` models from $main_query with the help of `ArrayHelper::getColumn`
3. create 2 custom array's to store `item_code` with your query result(amount/quantity) in it & use this array in your foreach loop.

You will find big time difference in execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query :

```
$connection = \Yii::$app->db;
$model = $connection->createCommand('select *, 
  (sum(select sum(count) from ProductIn where ProductIn.item_no = product.itemno) -
   sum(select sum(count) from ProductOut where ProductOut.item_no = product.itemno)) as availableQty
from product');
$products = $model->queryAll();
```

You need to import query class :

```
use yii\db\Query;
```